# Monitor BGP connections

Tags: monitoring, cisco, bgp

Do you know any special software for monitoring BGP peers, prefixes, log their failures, prefixes amount and etc? (Cisco)

( Not zabbix, nagios and etc, i know that you can write plugins or work with snmp, but I am searching for already written software )

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likewise, we monitor..

- Prefixes received by our speakers to a given threshold.
- Externally observed abnormalities: [IS Alarms](http://www.ripe.net/ris/) (was MyASN), [BGPmon](http://www.bgpmon.net/), [Renesys](http://www.renesys.com/).

SNMP is a really easy implemention for the former and probably the right road to go down.

Answer (score 1):

BGPmon.net may be what you are looking for--I use it, and it is fantastic.

"*BGP monitoring and analyzer tool*"

http://bgpmon.net/

-Josh

Comment: Yes, a very good tool but I do not think it addresses the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, all we did was write a Nagios SNMP plugin to check BGP peers were up and that they were advertising the number of routes we were expecting by checking it was between a high and low number (about ±10% of the advertised routes at the time we wrote the check).